# Why don't people access database in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I often see the code which uses mock in Rspec, like this:

```
describe "GET show" do
  it "should find and assign @question" do
    question = Question.new

    Question.should_receive(:find).with("123").and_return(question)
    get :show, :id => 123

    assigns[:question].should == question
  end
end
```

But why they don't add a `Question` with id => 123 in database, retrieve it by `get`, and destroy it? Is this a best practice? If I don't follow the rule, will something bad happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write a behavioral test (or a unit test), you're trying to test only a specific part of code, and not the entire stack.

To explain this better, you are just expressing and testing that "function A should call function B with these parameters", so you are testing function A and not function B, for which you provide a mock.

This is important for a number of reasons:

1. You don't need a database installed on every machine you build your code, this is important if you start using build machines (and/or continuous integration) in your company with hundreds of projects.
2. You get better test results, cause if function B is broken, or the database is not working properly, you don't get a test failure on function A.
3. Your tests run faster.
4. It's always a pain to have a clean DB before each test. What if a previous run of your tests was stopped, leaving on the database a Question with that id? You'll probably get a test failure because of duplicate id, while in reality the function is working properly.
5. You need a proper configuration before running your test. This is not such an incredible problem, but it's much better if tests can run "out of the box", without having to configure a database connection, a folder of temporary test files, an SMTP server for testing email stuff, etc...

A test that actually test the entire stack is called "end to end testing", or "integration testing" (depending on what it tests). These are important as well, for example a suite of tests without mock database can be used to see if a given application can run safely of a different DB than the one used during development, and eventually fix functions that contain offending SQL statements.

Comment: Can I say this: if I **have to** access DB in a test(e.g. I can't test the keywords search feature without some articles in DB), it should be a integration test?

Comment: I would say that if for testing a certain thing you REALLY need something else than your code and your test suite (including mocks etc..), then that test is actually also testing something else, so it's an integration test. However, it's not alway easy to determine what is "properly" part of an application and what is not, and also is not always completely possible to write a test based only on mocks. In those cases, placing those test in a separate suite that does not run "by default" is good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, many people do, including me. Generally speaking, since tests are there to check behavior, it can feel a bit unnatural to insert database entries to some people.

Question.new would be enough because it goes through the valid methods of rails anyway, so many people tend to use them, also because they are faster.

But, indeed, even if you start using factories, there will be times that you will probably inserting data to your testing environment as well. I personally don't see anything wrong with this.

Overall, in some situations were the testing suite is really large, it can be quite an advantage not to save database entries. But if speed is not your top concern, i would say that you would not really have to worry on how the test looks, as long as it is well constructed and to the point.

BTW, you do not need to destroy test data, it's done automatically after the test ends. So, unless you are checking on the actual delete methods, avoid doing that explicitly.

Comment: > *it's done automatically after the test ends.* is it to depend it safe? The DB will be clean after every example? Even it's stopped unexpectedly?

Comment: Yes, the db will clean after the tests run. If it stops unexpectedly, it will clean on the next run. Seriously, you don't need to care about cleanup.