# How should I mock my session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've set up a controller I'm testing so that most requests to its actions redirect to the sign_in page if a session doesn't exist.

Because of this, I need to use the `sign_in` method when testing controllers in a unit test. I also need to create the user in the database so they can sign in.

This is all easily achieved like this:

```
describe MyController, do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user)} # The 'create' creates in the database as well as in memory
    context "with session" do
        before {
            sign_in user
        }    

        context ".index" do
            assigns(:example).should == "Just an example"
        end
    end
end
```

However, this isn't a good unit test because it's depending on active record and the database, as well as Devise's test helper methods.

So how can I use a mock (or something) to stop my controller redirecting me when I'm trying to test it?

My controller:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:index]

    def index
        @example = "Just an example"
    end
end
```

Comment: It's a good automated test. Never mock something that would work anyway using production code like this. Only mock things like the clock, or a network connection.

Comment: But shouldn't I purely be testing my controller and nothing else in a controller spec?

Comment: Somewhat relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179482/why-dont-people-access-database-in-rspec

Comment: The goal of testing is to increase, not reduce, the odds something breaks if you create a bug. So the more tests call real things the better

Comment: With a feature or request spec I'd agree with you, but not in a unit spec.

Comment: Controller specs test module in itself, not the entire app.  The spec 's main purpose is to ensure that "this module" is behaving properly.

Comment: I just really like the idea breaking all the aspects of a huge application down into tiny little self contained rspec examples. It helps to get your head around everything to just think: "right, when this action receives a hash (no matter where it's from) in behaves in this manner." Just forgetting about the action's preceding model and proceeding view makes it very easy to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Stub user authentication as advised here in the [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs).